# how to call a function from node block scripted pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

am trying to understand the below line why do we need to call a stage with  .call()

## buildStage(slurper).call()  can someone explain me what this line means why cant we just call with
buildStage(slurper)

```
def call(String jsonString) {
  node("unix") {
  try {
        def slurper = new JsonSlurperClassic().parseText(jsonString)        
        buildStage(slurper).call() 
        deployStage()

        }catch(error) {
            println ex.toString()
        }finally{
            sendEmail() 
        }
    }
}     

def buildStage(slurper){
   stage ('Build') {

    }
}

def deployStage(slurper){
   stage ('Deploy') {

    }
}
```

Comment: Is that content you have got from Jenkinsfile or from a Jenkins Shared library?

[groovy closure](https://groovy-lang.org/closures.html) says that to call a groovy closure with the call() method is optional. The call() method executed on its own while using the closure.

Comment: from shared library . This is called from jenkins file using shared library in the var folder ( global function)

say the above code is in file in var  dir  alltech.groovy

in Jenkins file calling this function alltech()

@Library ("prov-shared-library") _

alltech( '''{

"nodeLabel" : "unix", 

  " deployEnv" : "devl"

}"")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your above example `buildStage(slurper).call()`  is not needed as it can be called like `buildStage(slurper)`,
methondName.call() is needed if the method has a closure block that needs to be executed upon calling, see my below example

**myPipeline.groovy**

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic

def call(String jsonString) {
    node() {
        try {
            def slurper = new JsonSlurperClassic().parseText(jsonString)
            buildStage(slurper)
            println deployStage(slurper).call()

        }catch(Exception ex ) {
            throw ex;
        }finally{
            // do nothing
        }
    }
}

def buildStage(slurper){
    stage ('Build') {
         return {
            println slurper
            def r = 5 + 5
            println r
        }.call()

    }
}

def deployStage(slurper){
    stage ('Deploy') {
        return {
            return "The name is "+ slurper.name
        }

    }
}
```

**Jenkinsfile**

```
def myJSON = '''
    { "name" : "XYZ"}
'''
myPipeline(myJSON)
```